# Is there a better way to write if (argList[foo] === "bar" || argList === "bar")?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, if-statement

I have an `if` statement :

```js
if (argList["foo"] === "bar" || argList === "bar"){
    // some code
}
```

I want to know if there is a shorter or more elegant way to write this condition.

Why i write this statement like this ?
I have a function called startTool(argList), and another called startCreate(argList).

```js
mod.zsh_apiStartTool = function(argList, callback) {
  
        // some code
  if (argList["tool"] === "measure" || argList === "measure"){
   //some code to start the tool
  }
  if (argList["tool"] === "scanning"|| argList === "scanning"){
   // some code to start the tool
  }
  ZSH_JS_API_ERROR(callback);
  return;
 }
```

```js
mod.zsh_apiStartCreate = function(argList, callback) {
  
        // some code
  if (argList["tool"] === "measure"){
   mod.zsh_apiStartTool("measure")
  }
  if (argList["tool"] === "scanning"){
   mod.zsh_apiStartTool("scanning");
  }
  ZSH_JS_API_ERROR(callback);
  return;
 }
```

So when i run into startTool from startCreate, my var isn't argList["foo"] === "bar" but argList === "bar"

Comment: So `argList` can either be an array, object or a string?

Comment: @Lain You mean an object?

Comment: First, `argList` it is an object or a string ?

Comment: I don't think enums are JavaScript. Do you mean an object?

Comment: Enums are probably sets.

Comment: You could write `if ([argList["foo"], argList].includes('bar')) {...} `, but why?

Comment: @Lain  argList is an enum array like {"name":"showSomething", "m":true, "type":"boolean", "enum":["true","false"]}

Comment: @Kub Network: How does the second `if` make sense if it is always an object? As long as you do not implement a toString which validates to 'bar' it wont ever be true.

Comment: @Lain It make sense when i use recursive implementation in my API, sometimes i can't use the same array

Comment: @Kub Network: If you say so.. I mean you said argList is always an object, so I can not see the use of the second `if`. But that is just me.

Comment: @Lain You are right, it's a contextual usage... long to explain. argList is an enum

Comment: @lain i'll provide better exemple

Comment: i go with lain on this one. even in the new example just use one function passing a string and checking it and the other one passing an object and check the property. however do not mix those. it might look fancy and cool for you now but not for anyone who has to maintain that code a year later. also dont use parametername argList if it aint a list.

Comment: You first check if it's a string and then check if it's an object with a property having certain value?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes !

Comment: @KubNetwork I mean the check should rather be `if (argList === "bar" || argList["foo"] === "bar"){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure that a property exists IMHO is better to use an helper as:

- typescript *elvis case*
- Lodash `_.get()` method

  `if (_.get(argList, "foo") === "bar" || argList === "bar"){
             // some code
     }`

The problem is critical only if you try to access to a deeper level like argList["foo"]["bar"]

**JSON.stringify**

Another option can be stringify the object and seek the value here, if you **know** that "bar" is a deterministic value in your object (so there is no other properties that can hold it in argList):

```
JSON.stringify(argListObj).includes("bar")
```

```js
const argListObj = { foo: "bar" };
const argListString = "bar";
console.log(JSON.stringify(argListObj).includes("bar"));
console.log(JSON.stringify(argListString).includes("bar");

// Console logs true, true
```

Comment: Because if nesting of the variable is a property of a property your code will blow with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "xxx" of undefined